# At each iteration I am 'redefining/reallocating' or restoring a variable, does this take extra space?

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have written a solution for the following problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-all-adjacent-duplicates-in-string-ii/

To summarise the question, we are given an `integer k`, and we need to `remove duplicates of length k`, from the `input string s`.

In my solution, I write out all the possible duplicates, which is an array of 26 elements. Then I iterate over the input string s, and remove the duplicates from it, or rather, I use slicing to `redefine s`:

```
def removeDuplicates(s: str, k: int) -> str:
        dup = [k * i for i in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"]

        pointer1 = 0
        while pointer1+k<len(s):
            if s[pointer1:pointer1+k] in dup:
                s = s[:pointer1] + s[pointer1+k:]
                if pointer1>1:
                    pointer1-=2*k

            if s[-k:len(s)] in dup:
                s = s[:-k]

            else:
                pointer1+=1

        return s
```

My understanding is that the `time complexity is O(n)`, where n is the length of the input string, since in the worst case we iterate over the whole string without removing any characters. Is this correct?

The `space complexity` is where I am more unsure, as each time I find a duplicate, I am redefining s, so will need to allocate 'new' space for this. Is it right to say that the space complexity is O(n) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on the language you are working on. Like java have garbage collector and similar thing is also there in python. But in c there we can say we have O(n) space complexity.